# Parameter is not valid error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am getting parameter is not valid error.how to solve this problem?

The following code is server side

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ObjDt.ImgUpload);                  
                ms.Write(ObjDt.ImgUpload, 0, ObjDt.ImgUpload.Length);                
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);               
                image.Dispose();                
                image.Save(@"D:\Projects\WCF\WCF_ImageUpload\DamagedImages\" + strRandNo + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);                
                // image.Save(@"C:\DotNet\ImageUpload\DamagedImages\" + strRandNo + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                //return strRandNo.ToString();
                string val = strRandNo.ToString();
IPAddress = "localhost:53865/WCF/Image" + val + ".jpg";
```

In these code i m getting Parameter is not valid error..Web config for these code is

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

<services>      
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <!-- <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding1" contract="WCF_ImageUpload.IService1"></endpoint>-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="StreamedBinding" bindingName="ServiceBehavior"
                          contract="WCF_ImageUpload.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

I have use the following client application in Windows application.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:53865/Service1.svc/UploadDamagedImage");
            Details ObjDt = new Details();
            ObjDt.Name = "hi";
            ObjDt.Email = "hi@gmail.com";
            ObjDt.ContactNumber = "3698754215";
            ObjDt.DeviceModel = "E23";
            ObjDt.Problem = "Repair";
            ObjDt.Besttimetocontact = "9am";
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:/WCFImages/admin.png");
ObjDt.ImgUpload = bytes;
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Details));
            // xmlserializer xser = new xmlserializer();
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(mem, ObjDt);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", data);
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line gives you this error?

Comment: post the exception message

Answer (score 0):

*Please tell us the line where the exception occurs - also, please provide a stack trace. The following is just what I'm seeing from a quick glance at the code you posted...*

This line is not valid C# syntax:

```
IPAddress = "http://localhost:53865/WCF/Image" + val + ".jpg";
```

Also, the string doesn't represent an IP-Address, so it can not be assigned to an object of type `IPAddress`. I'm assuming that `IPAddress` is not a variable name, as naming conventions for C# state the variable names should start with small letter.

In addition to that, the code is flawed. You're creating the image, then you dispose it and then you try to save it.

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);               
image.Dispose();                
image.Save(@"D:\Projects\WCF\WCF_ImageUpload\DamagedImages\" + strRandNo + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It should be the other way: create, save, dispose:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);               
image.Save(@"D:\Projects\WCF\WCF_ImageUpload\DamagedImages\" + strRandNo + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
image.Dispose();
```

Or even better:

```
using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true))              
{
    image.Save(@"D:\Projects\WCF\WCF_ImageUpload\DamagedImages\" + strRandNo + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
}
```

**EDIT**
In your comment you are saying that the line where you load the image from the stream throws the error. This leads to the following you should check:

It is redundant (and even an error in your case) to execute the following two lines:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ObjDt.ImgUpload);                  
ms.Write(ObjDt.ImgUpload, 0, ObjDt.ImgUpload.Length);
```

The first line creates the memory stream that's based on the bytes given in `ObjDt.ImgUpload` (the stream already "contains the image" after that line). You then write the bytes to the stream *once more*. Either remove the parameter from the stream's constructor or remove the line that writes the bytes to the stream.

All in all these two lines lead to the stream not containing valid image data, as it contains the image bytes twice in a row. Also I'm not sure about the `bool` parameter that indicates the presence of color management information within the stream - remove it for testing purposes. The code should read:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ObjDt.ImgUpload))
using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))              
{
    image.Save(@"D:\Projects\WCF\WCF_ImageUpload\DamagedImages\" + strRandNo + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
}
```

Comment: Here, i am getting parameter is not valid error                     Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: I edited my reply. In short, the stream contains the image bytes twice.

Comment: If i used dispose() after save image, i am getting the error.Like,   A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: That's a different matter - it *can not* be the other way around (a disposed object can not be used, so it can't be saved). Please incorporate what I said in my edit about the stream first and then come back if there are other problems.

Comment: Now i am trying this edited code..I m getting the following errors   1. "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
2. "Timeout error not supported this stream"

Comment: Are you sure that `ObjDt.ImgUpload` contains valid image data? Can you write the data to a file directly and open it in Paint?

Comment: Did you save the bytes on the server side and verify this? Can you provide the method declaration of the method that's being called via WCF?

Comment: The image saved in server side only.. the method declaration is, [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadDamagedImage", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]        
        NewClsMessage UploadDamagedImage(Details ObjDt);

Comment: Well, then this may be a source of problems: For a streamed contract, methods may only take a parameter of type `Stream`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36973/Stream-Operation-in-WCF. Considering this, you would have to read all text from the given stream, deserialize the JSON object you serialized in your call and *then* use the image bytes. This also means that you did not (as I asked above) test whether `ObjDt.ImgUpload` contains valid image byte on the server side.

Comment: Good to hear - feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer :-)